# How to enable nginx ingress for end-to-end tls connection

Tags: nginx, kubernetes, nginx-ingress

How can I enable nginx ingress to support end-to-end TLS connection without passthrough. The Ingress LoadBalancer is allowed with PublicCA and backend servers are also running on TLS port with PrivateCA

[image]

The following ingress definition will do the TLS offloading with the Public certificate installed on the Edge.

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
  name: wbqgdimtzx
  namespace: default
spec:
  rules:
  - host: 0cloud0.com
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          serviceName: wbqgdimtzx
          servicePort: 443
        path: /
  tls:
  - hosts:
    - 0cloud0.com
  secretName: 0cloud0-wildcard-certs
status:
  loadBalancer:
    ingress:
    - {}
```

The backend pods are running on secure port where plain text connection is not allowed for security reasons.

What upstream changes do I need to do in the nginx ingress to support the end-to-end setting?

Based on Amit Response added

> nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/backend-protocol: HTTPS

It worked [https://cunkexvoxu.0cloud0.com/](https://0cloud0.com/)

Comment: have you tried: https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/nginx-configuration/annotations/#backend-protocol

Comment: @AmitKumarGupta After adding backed protocol its throwing Bad Gateway

Comment: @AmitKumarGupta The Bad Gateway is Resolved Thanks for your Suggestion

Comment: @AmitKumarGupta could you add your solution as an answer? It will make your solution more visible if anyone will be searching for similar issues.

Answer (score 1):

Based on @Amit Kumar Gupta comment, I am posting this as community wiki for better visibility.

As OP in his YAML specified backend with `servicePort: 443` and `tls`, however it was not enought to ensure secure end2end connection.
NGINX as default is using `HTTP`. If you want to reach your service only as `HTTPS` you have to add annotation to `Ingress` YAML.

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: wbqgdimtzx
  namespace: default
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/backend-protocol: "HTTPS"
...
```